# iOS, Node.js: Firebase Push Notification JSON signature

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase documentation asks to implement like this, which gets success return value on node.js server. But the notification does not deliver.

From Firebase Cloud Messaging Console, all the notifications/messages gets delivered.
Also from plain APNS works too, except the below case.

This particular JSON signature does not confirm to APNS. When I give APNS compatible JSON, Firebase returns error.

```
// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationToken = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN';

var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

What to do to be able to work?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from Google's Firebase sample code. And, it works.

```
{
        "token": "<<YOUR FCM TOKEN>>",
        "notification": {
            "body": "Notification from FCM",
            "title": "FCM Notification"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "click_action": "android.intent.action.MAIN"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "10"
            },
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "badge": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```